# AWS API Gateway POST route keeps returning "message": "Not Found"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I cannot get API Gateway POST route to return properly when linked to my working AWS Lambda.

**Problem:** When I use Postman (or anything else) to test POST method on API Gateway, the API Gateway keep returning "message": "Not Found".

**Details:** In Postman, I am using the exact same Body under "raw" as my Lambda Event JSON test and am *not* using any Params or Headers. There is no CORS issue as well.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: postman screenshot]

Lambda test Event JSON returns:

```
{

"statusCode": 200,

"body": "{\"message\":\"Received data:\",\"data\":{\"data\":\"Hello, Lambda!\"}}"

}
```

Event JSON code:

```
{

"body": "{\"data\": \"Hello, Lambda!\"}",

"httpMethod": "POST",

"isBase64Encoded": false,

"headers": {

"Content-Type": "application/json"

},

"path": "/your-path"

}
```

My AWS Lambda code:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {

try {

const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);



const responseData = {

message: 'Received data:',

data: requestBody,

};

return {

statusCode: 200,

body: JSON.stringify(responseData),

};

} catch (error) {

// Handle any errors that occur during execution

console.error('Error:', error);

return {

statusCode: 500,

body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'An unexpected error occurred.' }),

};

}

};
```

API Gateway info:

POST

https://yiea29chwl.execute-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/track_req_submit

Body (raw):

```
{

"body": "{\"data\": \"Hello, Lambda!\"}",

"httpMethod": "POST",

"isBase64Encoded": false,

"headers": {

"Content-Type": "application/json"

},

"path": "/track_req_submit"

}
```

API Gateway has 2 routes: i) ANY, ii) POST

Post:
POST /track_req_submit

and it is configured to my Lambda function:

Integration
The integration is the backend resource that this route calls when it receives a request.
xbmf7fm

Comment: `{"message":"Not Found"}` is technically an HTTP 404 status code. It looks like the API Gateway routing isn't set correctly, meaning that you're trying to fetch an item that doesn't exist in the requested path or you're using an incorrect path in the requested URL. Can you provide some details on what the API gateway routing and stages look like?